# Сброс таймера js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Каким образом можно сбрасывать таймер? при нажатие закрыть уведомление (Close или Message).

```
 $(document).on('click', '.close, .message', function() {
        $(".message").animate({bottom: "-100",opacity: 0.0,}, 'fast', function() {$('.message').remove();});

    });

    function messages(status,text) {
            $("div").remove(".message");
            $("body").append('<div class="message"><div class="message'+status+'"></div><span>'+text+'</span><div class="close"></div></div>');
             setTimeout("if($('div').is('.message'))$('.message').animate({bottom: '-100',opacity: 0.0,}, 'fast', function() {$('.message').remove();});",3000)
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych нужно бы еще указать что именно искать)

Comment: @Cheg ну там пол оборота колесом вниз и `Отмена исполнения clearTimeout`, не думаю что сложно найти будет :)